# My Salesforce free trial is about to expire. Will my trailhead playground expire with it too?

Tags: trailhead

My Salesforce free trial is about to expire. The current account shows username same as my Trailhead Playgroud username. If it so happens that my trial period expires tomorrow, will my playground be deleted too?
Also, would that mean all my progress on Trailhead (playground part) will be erased as well?
Note: I do not have any other playground, and am using the default one.

Answer (score 1):

Create a developer account and link it to your Trailhead account.
You can do it from [setting](https://trailblazer.me/settings) page of the trailhead.

Even you can migrate your account to a new developer account.

You can also connect the Social accounts like Google, FB, and LinkedIn from the Settings page.

Sign up [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup) for developer edition org.